# WebvView zoom not working in android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView Android

Tags: android, webview, zooming

I have created Browser in Android, in that I am using **AppBarLayout** and **NestedScrollView** for scroll to hide/show header. But there are one issue occurs pinch to zoom is disabled after adding webview in NestedScrollView.

My xml code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

    <android.support.design.widget.CustomAppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp" >

            <LinearLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/black"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/statusbar_height" >

                <LinearLayout
                    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center" >

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/favicon"
                            android:layout_width="32dp"
                            android:layout_height="32dp"
                            android:contentDescription="@string/favicon"
                            android:src="@drawable/favicon_default" />

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/url"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:ems="10"
                            android:inputType="textUri"
                            android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white" >
                        </EditText>

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/goButton"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:onClick="go"
                            android:text="@string/go" />
                    </LinearLayout>                     
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.CustomAppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollWeb"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Zoom code for WebView:

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

Thanks.

Comment: it is customWebView, try using only WebView

Comment: @DemoMail, I tried using WebView, same result

Comment: did you find solution?

Comment: could you send link on your app?

Comment: My app is now in development mode

Comment: I used https://github.com/takahirom/webview-in-coordinatorlayout, works well.

Comment: Have any solution for this issue?